# How to use a sum with low and upper bound in R

Tags: r

I would like to write this equation in R code:

```
log(100) + log(2!) + $\Sum_{j=1}^{5} (log(5)/j)$
```

I just do not know to convert the last term of the equation into R code. I tried this:

```
log(100)+log(factorial(2))+{for(i in 1:5) sum(log(5)/i)}
```

but I got `numeric(0)`

Comment: Try `sum(log(5)/seq_len(5))`

Comment: @akrun very helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: There is no need for a loop, but you can do this with `s1 <- 0;
 for(i in 1:5) s1 <- s1 + log(5)/i`

Comment: @akrun Many thanks.

Comment: R is vectorized. So you can declare `v <- 1:5` then reference `log(5) / v` or in your case `sum(log(5) / v)`. And in fact you can reduce all that to `sum(log(5) / (1:5))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` loop, `sum(log(5)/i)` doesn't do anything as it is a single number.  E.g. it would be wrapping `sum` to `log(5)/i`, then `log(5)/2` individually, instead of taking the whole `sum`.

One option in a `for` loop is to a initiate a variable ('s1') with a value (0) and then assign the value got in each loop to 's1' while adding it with the earlier value.

```
s1 <- 0
for(i in 1:5) s1 <- s1 + log(5)/i
```

---

But, it can be vectorized by dividing the `log(5)` by the sequence of rows to get a `vector` of values, and then wrap with `sum`

```
sum(log(5)/seq_len(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

R is vectorized.

So you can declare `v <- 1:5` then reference `log(5) / v` or in your case `sum(log(5) / v)`.

And in fact you can reduce all that to `sum(log(5) / (1:5))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I should select the answer of the @akrun as it was the first (as a comment). I really appreciate your help and thank you so much again for that.

Comment: Maryam: sure. Read about vectorization in R, for expressions. You almost never need a for-loop. Also, vectorization will almost always give you shorter, clearer, faster code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will read. I really do not know how to thank you and @akrun for your help.